# ASP auto-generating href target differently on production server

Tags: asp.net, iis, href

Please help. When I run a basic aspx website on a test server (IIS 8.5), href links do not have a target value and default to opening in the same page. This is desired.

When I copy the same website to the production server, ASP auto-adds target="_blank" to all the hyperlinks causing the pages to open in new tabs.

The servers are both 2012 R2 running IIS 8.5. Both sites use version 4 of the .Net framework in classic mode for the Application Pool.

What could possibly cause the production server to auto-add a target value for the href hyperlinks?

For example, this is what is actually written:

```
<a id="Header_financial" href="Financials.aspx">Financial Information</a>
```

In the production server, this is what shows in the debugger window of any browser:

```
<a id="Header_financial" href="Financials.aspx" target=_blank">Financial Information</a>
```

If I debug the site in any web browser on the test server, there is no target= in the hyperlink and all is well. When I run the same exact code on the production server, somehow it auto-generates/adds target="_blank". If I add target="_self" to the aspx page, _blank still gets auto-generated.

Any ideas? This is driving me nuts.